Pentaho: I used "Modified JavaScript value" to get Dynacmic date value in MongoDB input to query in JSON, but it`s not working
I have used following code in "Modified JavaScript value"
    var startOfToday = new Date();
    startOfToday.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    var endOfToday = new Date();
    endOfToday.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

    var isoStartOfToday = startOfToday.toISOString();
    var isoEndOfToday = endOfToday.toISOString();

The variables are created and displaying when logging. But when using the MongoDB Input method and querying using JSON code and writing the following code it`s not working.
{
  "createdOn": {
    "$gte": { "$date": "${isoStartOfToday}" },
    "$lt": { "$date": "${isoEndOfToday}" }
  }
}

Log:
startOfToday = 2024/07/22 00:00:00.000
endOfToday = 2024/07/22 23:59:59.999
isoStartOfToday = 2024-07-21T18:30:00.000Z
isoEndOfToday = 2024-07-22T18:29:59.999Z

When I put these values statically I get the response correct.
